# cURL - Invalid character is found in given range 'start' - 'stop'

Tags: api, http, rest, curl

I'm making a restful api call, but I'm getting an error.

```
Warning: Invalid character is found in given range. A specified range MUST 
Warning: have only digits in 'start'-'stop'. The server's response to this 
Warning: request is uncertain.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2013 17:43:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 208
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST
Vary: Authorization
Content-Type: application/json
```

Has anyone seen this WARNING error before about an invalid character? How do I fix it?

I was calling:

```
curl https://my/url/for/api --include -H "Content-Type:application/json" -request POST '{ \"type\": \"code\", \"objects\" : [ \"123456\" ] } ' -u user:pass
```

More info:

extra response at the end of return

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; nodename nor servname provided, or not known

curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos 33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar situation - my `curl` request was essentially working, and returning the information I needed, but with warnings, using the following code:

```
curl -request http://...
```

It turned out to be the `-request` parameter, which I'd incorrectly typed.  It either needs to be something like:

```
curl --request GET http://...
```

or simply not there at all (because GET is the default):

```
curl http://...
```

Answer (score 3):

A corrected command line probably looks something like:

```
curl https://my/url/for/api \
--include \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{ \"type\": \"code\", \"objects\" : [ \"123456\" ] } ' \
-u user:pass
```

(I split it to multiple lines for readability.) The changes I did:

1 - --request needs two dashes but since you set POST, it was superfluous and I removed it

2 - use -d (or --data) to specify what to POST. --request only takes a single method string
that you can *replace* POST with in the HTTP request but I don't think you want that.

Answer (score 2):

cURL gets confused about the square brackets in your command. It interprets them as a range of characters it should process. Either way your question would probably fit better on SuperUser than on Stackoverflow.